# UTC datetime conversion to local time

Tags: c#, mysql, utc, timezone-offset, localtime

I store data into MySql datetime field and I was saving there always UTC date from C# (using
**someDate.ToUniversalTime()**).

I am in Central European timezone.

I have one date that was saved on 08.03.2016 as 2016-04-07 16:00:00 (event was set in the future at that time) and correct local time for this event was  2016-04-07 17:00:00, so it was saved as GMT+1 at that time. I used **someDate.ToLocalTime()** to get correct local time and it worked well.

Today (in April), because of DayLight event that occured at the end of March we have GMT+2 offset and now **someDate.ToLocalTime()** shows me 1 hour more: 2016-04-07 18:00:00 which is not correct.

How to solve this universally? 
I want to save UTC time (as now) and then to apply some system conversion that use user's current timezone and always return correct local time from my saved UTC date regarding the current DayLightSaving status.
It should also return 2016-04-07 17:00:00 and not 2016-04-07 18:00:00

Comment: Use `TIMESTAMP` rather than `DATETIME` and then set the `time_zone` session variable—MySQL will handle the rest.

Comment: Is this a desktop app, or a web app?  In general, only desktop applications should be using `ToLocalTime` and `ToUniversalTime`.

Answer (score 4):

Your assumption is wrong: The valid localtime for 2016-04-07 16:00 UTC in Central Europe Timezone is always 2016-04-07 18:00 and never was 2016-04-07 17:00. You must calculate the UTC offset always with respect to the date you are looking at and not the current date.

Try the following code. It will always print the same values, regardless of your current date (ie whether you are currently in daylightsaving or not)

```
var dt1 = new DateTime(2016, 3, 1, 15, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var dt2 = new DateTime(2016, 5, 1, 15, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

var s1 = dt1.ToLocalTime().ToString("s");
var s2 = dt2.ToLocalTime().ToString("s");

Console.WriteLine(s1);  //prints 2016-03-01T16:00:00  because GMT+1 at that date
Console.WriteLine(s2);  //prints 2016-05-01T17:00:00  because GMT+2 at that date
```